# Appropriate way to allocate study time for a multi-subject, weighted scoring exam.

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm preparing for a government exam that consists of three tests, each contributing to a final score. The structure and scoring of the tests are as follows:

**Test 1:** Comprises 20 questions across 6 subjects (equal weight). Score is calculated as (Correct Answers * 100) / 20.

**Test 2:** Contains 50 questions across 5 subjects (varying weights). Score is calculated as (Correct Answers per subject * Weight per subject). The score is obtained by summing all the results together.

**Test 3:** Scored out of 100 points.

The exam allows me to compete for three different positions, each with different subject weights for Test 2:

**Position 1 (highest pay, highest priority):** Weights are 3, 3, 2, 1, 1.

**Position 2 (second priority):** All weights are 2.

**Position 3 (third priority):** Weights are 2, 2, 1, 3, 2.

The final scores for each position are calculated as follows:

**Position 1:** Test 1 (20%), Test 2 (50%), Test 3 (20%). An additional 10 points are available, but I don't qualify for these.

**Positions 2 and 3:** Test 1 (25%), Test 2 (55%), Test 3 (20%).

I'm currently trying to figure out how to allocate my study time across the 11 subjects (6 for Test 1, 5 for Test 2, and 1 for Test 3), considering the importance of each position. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has no mathematical answer. You should think about which subjects you are strong in, which weak, and which ones it might pay to strengthen by studying.

Comment: No I believe there's a mathematical answer to this question, provided the answerer makes some basic assumptions about the test taker (i.e. studying in one subject produces just as much improvement as studying in a different subject)

Comment: @EthanBolker I got the exact answer I was looking for. I'm sorry but I'm really bad at math so I didn't know what was the mathematical answer to this. I needed it to write an Excel Macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's list out the weight of each of the $12$ subjects for the three positions (given as percentages).

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Subjects \rightarrow & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\
\hline
Position 1 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 15 & 15 & 10 & 5 & 5 & 20 \\ \hline
Position 2 & 4.16 & 4.16 & 4.16 & 4.16 & 4.16 & 4.16 & 11 & 11 & 11 & 11 & 11 & 20 \\ \hline
Position 3 & 4.16 & 4.16 & 4.16 & 4.16 & 4.16 & 4.16 & 11 & 11 & 5.5 & 16.5 & 11 & 20 \\ \hline
Average & 3.87 & 3.87 & 3.87 & 3.87 & 3.87 & 3.87 & 12.3 & 12.3 & 8.83 & 10.83 & 9 & 20 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Let's assume you have equal amount of time available to study for each test (i.e. they are all on the same day). Let's also assume that your current knowledge and studying efficiency is uniform across all $12$ subjects, and also that each subject has the same difficulty. If so, then to study for a particular position you need to allocate your study time accordingly based on the corresponding row in the table.

Let's also assume that you just want a job, so all three positions are valued the same. If so, then you should allocate your study time based on the "Average" row.

I know that you said you prioritize some positions more than others, but in order to give a quantifiable answer you need to quanitfy how much you value each position over the others. E.g. do you value Position $1$ twice as much or three times as much as Position $2$? Once you figure out your weights for the three positions, you can take a weighted average of the columns instead of a regular average like I did.

Comment: Thank you, you're awesome!!!

That's precisely what I was looking for.

Now I can go ahead and write the excel macro that'll calculate how much time I should spend on each. And I liked your comment about weighting the three different jobs.

Thank you very much.

Comment: just one more question though. I just realized I had written something wrong about test 2. It shouldn't change much, but the score of test 2 is actually the sum of the individual subject scores .

Anyway, thanks.

Comment: I don't think that would affect anything, because in any case each of the five subjects would still make up the same percentage of Test $2$'s content.